# Permission denied when running Emacs from Cygwin console

Tags: permissions, emacs, cygwin

When I run Emacs from the Cygwin console I get the following error message:

> bash: /usr/bin/emacs/ :Permission denied

I have not changed any settings. I tried to change the autosave settings in the Emacs system file but that didn't work so I deleted it and saved the file.

It was after that that I started getting this error.

Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: What is the output of ls -l /usr/bin/emacs

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to go ahead and run chmod +x /usr/bin/emacs This will allow the owner, members of the same group, and everyone else be able to execute the application.

The permission may be set to rw-r-r or something like that.